# Omit headers in requests POST request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am making a POST request using the `import requests` library. It's adding some headers to the request that I suspect is making it fail...

```
r = requests.post(url, headers = {"Content-Type" : "text/zinc; charset=utf-8"}, \
                  cookies = {"cookie":cookie}, \
                  data = data)
```

Here's the results of `r.request.headers`...

```
CaseInsensitiveDict({
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Content-Type': 'text/zinc; charset=utf-8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress',
    'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/3.4.0 Linux/3.13.0-52-generic',
    'Cookie': 'cookie=mycookie; fanws="mycookie"'
})
```

So the question is, how do I only include the headers that I specified?

Comment: The other headers are perfectly sensible and added automatically, because the HTTP specification states that they are required or they communicate what type of responses `requests` can handle.. Why do you think they are a problem?

Comment: Also, where did the `Content-Length` header go? It would normally be added for you, but your `r.request.headers` is missing that one. I'm also not seeing the expected `Connection: keep-alive` header.

Answer (score 2):

You can use session to hack all requests you are sending through it.

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

session.headers = {}

response = session.post('http://example.com')

print response.request.headers
```

Comment: This won't clear the default headers like `Content-Length` set on the request that goes out. For full control using a prepared request is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, you can create a [`PreparedRequest`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) and then edit its headers before sending it. This is unlikely to help you here—but it may be worth doing just to convince yourself that it's not going to help, so…

Instead of this:

```
r = requests.post(url, headers = {"Content-Type" : "text/zinc; charset=utf-8"}, \
                  cookies = {"cookie":cookie}, \
                  data = data)
```

Do this:

```
sess = requests.Session()
req = requests.Request('GET', url, 
                       headers={"Content-Type": "text/zinc; charset=utf-8"},
                       cookies={"cookie": cookie},
                       data=data)
preq = req.prepare()
preq.headers = {key: value for key, value in preq.headers.items()
                if key in {'Content-Type', 'Cookie'}}
r = sess.send(preq)
```

It's in `prepare` that all the changes get done. You obviously want to keep the `cookies` being turned into a `Cookie` header, but you don't want to keep any of the other changes, so I just removed any header besides the one you explicitly passed and `Cookie`. You can, of course, do anything else you want there.

Comment: I was holding of from showing how to manipulate what gets sent; the headers on the request are almost 100% certainly *not* the issue here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: As I said in the first paragraph, it may be worth doing just to convince himself that this isn't what he wants to do. Even if he trusts you implicitly, or thinks he understands HTTP well enough to get why he really does want an `Accept` header, that still isn't as convincing as seeing it run and get the same error. (Or, of course, getting a different error because the server doesn't want to respond to a request with a body without a `Content-Length` or something…)

Comment: But A. Haaji is correct in that using `Session` gives you the option to at least clear all the static headers. Only `Content-Length` will be set in that case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sure, but the OP is asking for full control over exactly the headers that go out. Showing him how to send exactly the headers he thinks he wants, in the most direct way, is nearly as simple as showing him how to get a little closer to what he thinks he wants, so why not actually do it?